# Why to use "this" for calling a function in jquery

Tags: jquery, oop, jquery-ui

I have the following code. In the below code, there are two functions calling to another function. But I can't understand why once that function is called with this and another time that same function is called by a variable in other place.

```
 var widgetMethods = {

    getWidgetData: function($widgetElement) {

          var widgetData = $widgetElement.data('widgetData');

          widgetData = (typeof widgetData == 'undefined')  ? { type: null, key: null } : widgetData;

          if( widgetData.type == null ) {
            console.log("Widget type is not specified!");
            return false;
          }

          if( widgetData.key == null ) {
            console.log("Widget key is not specified!");
            return false;

          }
          return widgetData;
        },

    editWidget: function(key, options) {  

          var $self = jQuery(this);
          var widgetData = widgetMethods.getWidgetData($self);
          }

    getWidgetTemplate: function($widgetElement) {

          var widgetData = this.getWidgetData($widgetElement);
          }


    }
```

Can someone help me. I am confused. Please describe briefly.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to the current pointer of the element calling the function. hence, you can pass the current element using "this". however, when you are calling a different function not referred by the same element, you need to pass the attribute of the same to use it.

still if you are confused look into this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd.aspx

:)

Comment: But why can't i call the getWidgetData in editWidget by this object

Comment: Dont use $self... use var self = $(this)
then,
var widgetData = widgetMethods.getWidgetData(self);